# How to DEFLATE with a command line tool to extract a page from Microsoft Server

Tags: encoding, deflate

How can I view html page from Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 with header: "Accept-Encoding: deflate"

- I can't decompress such html page in Linux(Centos).
- I can decompress with "Accept-Encoding: gzip"(gunzip).
- I can decompress with "Accept-Encoding: br"(brotli).

I want to uncompress page from Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 with header:

```
"Accept-Encoding: deflate".
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I'm looking for a command line wrapper for the DEFLATE algorithm.
Unfortunately:
`zlib-flate -uncompress < deflate.dat  > page.html flate: inflate: data: incorrect header check`

```
unpigz -c deflate.dat
unpigz: skipping: deflate.dat is not compressed
```

```
openssl zlib -d < deflate.dat > page.html
140264494790544:error:29065064:lib(41):BIO_ZLIB_READ:zlib inflate error:c_zlib.c:548:zlib error:data error
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft and their IIS server is what ruined the `deflate` HTTP content encoding for everyone. The [HTTP standard in RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5) clearly states:

```
deflate
    The "zlib" format defined in RFC 1950 [31] in combination with
    the "deflate" compression mechanism described in RFC 1951 [29].
```

However the authors at Microsoft of IIS did not read the standard, and instead decided on their own that `deflate` meant *raw* deflate, just RFC 1951, *without* the zlib wrapper. Then browsers either didn't work with `deflate` encoding, or they had to try decoding it both ways, with and without the zlib wrapper. Now the recommendation is to simply not use the `deflate` encoding, and use `gzip` instead.

I am not aware of a stock command line tool to decompress raw deflate data. You can compile this with zlib to create such a tool:

```c
// Decompress raw deflate data from stdin to stdout. Return with an exit code
// of 1 if there is an error.

#include <stdio.h>
#include "zlib.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define BINARY() (_setmode(0, _O_BINARY), _setmode(1, _O_BINARY))
#else
#  define BINARY()
#endif

int main(void) {
    BINARY();
    z_stream strm = {0};
    int ret = inflateInit2(&strm, -15);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return 1;
    unsigned char in[32768], out[32768];
    do {
        if (strm.avail_in == 0) {
            strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), stdin);
            strm.next_in = in;
        }
        strm.avail_out = sizeof(out);
        strm.next_out = out;
        ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        fwrite(out, 1, sizeof(out) - strm.avail_out, stdout);
    } while (ret == Z_OK);
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret != Z_STREAM_END;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i found decision:

`
cat deflate.dat | (printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" ; cat - ) | gzip -dc >page.html
`

Comment: Ok, sure. gzip will complain. Since you have pigz, you could also `echo -n x\^ | cat - deflate.dat | pigz -dz > page.html` (and pigz will complain as well).